# angular httpClient get orders with or without a filter by date

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular2-observables

I have specification date that says get orders where date = date1 >= :date and date2=< :date and if both dates are null it should return all orders basically 
basically both urls should pass from one service 
baseUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders';
  private filterUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders?start= &end= ';

How can i achieve this in angular service and how do i call it in my component
i started like this but im new to angular dont know how to go by the logic

```
  getOrders(From: Date, To: Date): Observable<Order[]> {
return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '?start=' + From + '&end=' +To)
  .pipe(map(this.extractData),
    tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}
what i want is for my html to show the whole list automatically and should filter if both dates are passed,my thoughts are i will not in this case need the baseUrl above i will use the filter url and defaults should be null 
can someone show me how to continue thank you.
here is my sql incase

```
SELECT orderId, petrolQty, orderDate, truckId from orderz \
where (orderDate>=:start or :start is null) and (orderDate<=:end or :end is null)
```

so basically i will be filtering by orderDate
So what i did now is this

```
 baseUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders';

  getOrders(From: Date, To: Date): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '?start=' + From + '&end='+To)
      .pipe(map(this.extractData),
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

and in my component i did this

```
  start: Date = null;
  end: Date = null;

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orders = this.getOrdersDto();
  }


  private getOrdersDto() {

    return this.orderService.getOrders(this.start, this.end)
  }
```

the url i set to null and tried on postman it gave exception unparcable date null, this is because i set them to null ,now the issue is can i create and if service get method ,that will use 'http://localhost:8088/orders when dates are set to null and when i put dates it will it will use the new dates to filter

Comment: What does your server-side API require for each of those cases? Your service end point dictates what data you send and how.

Comment: Yes i will update my question and tag you now

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel i just updated it after testing the url with post man note that if i use just base urls just orders ot will work now its about the null values that dates dont accepts

Comment: may be i should create two post methods for one for a form with filter dates and one will will implement  oninit method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing your URL dynamically, let Angular do that for you.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

baseUrl : string = 'http://localhost:8088/orders';

getOrders(from: Date, to: Date): Observable<Order[]> {
    const params = new HttpParams();

    if (from) {
        params.set('start', from);
    }

    if (to) {
        params.set('end', to);
    }

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, { params: params })
        ...;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. The code above will conditionally add your query parameters onto the request if they are not null. If they are null, your request will just be `http://localhost:8088/orders`. Otherwise your parameters will get sent along in the URL like `?start=...&end=...`.

Comment: what happens when one is null does it give and error or filters

Comment: I don't know what your server code does. This is only helping you properly construct your URLs based on what you stated. If one is null, it will not be sent as a query parameter. Only non-null ones will be sent with the request.

Comment: ok before you posted this i tried with two methods one with filter and the other without so when i tested it worked and even when one date was null it filtered using one date i thought it should fail given my sql query above,

Comment: i tried your post and it gives three erros date not asignable to String param and observable on the return line is not assignable to Orders

Comment: The parameters that get sent need to be strings. Either pass them as strings or call `toString()` on the values when setting them as a parameter. As for the other, it was just a sample. You will have to type the `get` method, for example `get<Order[]>`.

Comment: when i changed to strings i get 0 response and my log doesnt show any errors at all , but when i changed  date to toDateString i got an error response , i might add that i am using spring for server side and my controllers are annotated with @DateTimeFormat

Comment: so the conversion to strings is a problem

Comment: That is a separate question. You'll have to see what type of string format your date needs to be in and get the dates in that format when setting the parameter.